# Facing problem from getting double and int value from binary file

Tags: java, android

Can anybody please tell me how to get double and int value from a binary file. I have tried alot but its giving me wrong values. Here is my code.

```
InputStream iStream = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.map);

    DataInputStream input;

        input = new DataInputStream(iStream);   

            try {                   

double mapFileFormatVersionNumber, IntendedSoftwareVersion;         
int DemoDays;

mapFileFormatVersionNumber =input.readDouble();                     
IntendedSoftwareVersion = input.readDouble();
DemoDays = input.readInt();
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did the file come from? What's the format? The `DataInputStream` docs tell you the *expected* format - but presumably that's not the format of your actual file...

Comment: i have made a folder named Raw in RES and put my file in it. and my file format is .AMF (Anquet Map File).

Comment: @sajjoo: Do you have a link to the specification for that file type? Does it match DataInputStream's expected format?

Comment: actually i know the specifications of that file. where are the strings, integers, double, float i know that all. and i also code it having that specs in my mind. and strings results are okay but doubles and integers giving me wrong values.

Comment: they may not be of same bit length, they may not have the same endianness, etc. etc. And you should please kindly elaborate on your problem, not want us to read previous questions. All in all, you want US to help you, not the other way around. So *you* *should* do as much as possible for us to make it easy to help *you*.

Comment: i am sorry if you felt irritation because of me. i post it again

Comment: It's not irritation, I'm just trying to teach you to ask questions properly, that way you'll be able to get answers.

Comment: yes thanks i,l takecare of it for next time. but now i have to wait to post it again becuase it says user with 100 reputation can post a question in every 20 minutes.

Comment: edit this post, please do not post new posts for the same question!
currently you have four questions about reading *.amf* files.

Comment: Edit the post, do not post duplicate questions.

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate from the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414641/facing-problem-from-getting-double-and-int-value-from-binary-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in C++ and Java integer types. They are both signed 32-bit numeric types. However, its binary representation might be different depending on the [byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). For example, integer might be represented in file in little endian byte order and reading it assuming it is in big endian will result in wrong data. You might want to experiment with byte order if you don't know exactly how it is stored in the file. Take a look at [ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) Java class, it supports different byte orders.

Answer (score 1):

Tthere are a gazillion possible representations of integers and doubles. Hence you simply can't expect DataInputStream to be compatible with whatever bizarre binary format. You'll have to go through the specs of .AMF file format and roll your own conversion.